# How to allow only one checkbox checked at a time?

Tags: python, checkbox, pyqt, pyqt4, pyside

I am making a GUI for a script in Python, using PySide Qt. I have a couple of checkboxes in the main window and I was wondering if it is possible to make them dependant to each other. What I mean is that, if I check one of them, all the others should become unchecked. So only one can be checked at a time.

Is there a comfortable way to do this? Otherwise I would just write a function to uncheck the others.

Comment: Take a look at [`QButtonGroup`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/qbuttongroup.html)

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. Well now I don't manage to put the checkbox in each cell of my table, because the checkbox is now a QAbstractButton, not a QTableWidgetItem anymore. How do I get a QAbstractButton into a certain cell of a QTableWidget?

Comment: @user3429131 If you found an answer to your question, would you mind posting it here as an answer? This will help future visitors who may have the same problem as you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use QButtonGroup to make them as a group and you might want to derive a class from this and override the basic check/uncheck depending on how you want the checkboxes to behave